# How to collect arrays containing only specified key in JavaScript AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've look everywhere and I can't find the answer to this.

Can you specify an AJAX call to only return with arrays equal to the key provided?

I've made a simple randomizer and it works fine when you search in general, but when you filter the search it can take a hot minute to return the result because I've set it to pass a test equalling the variable 'query'. If it doesn't pass then the function starts over again until it returns a random array equaling the var query.

Naturally, I'd love to speed up the process. Can anyone make recommendations? I'm sure it's something simple and apologize in advance.

You can see the working demo here:
https://codepen.io/ohBretterson/pen/eLBPbQ?editors=0010

I imagine I have to manipulate my data object after **success:**

```
function getTreasure() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://codepen.io/ohBretterson/pen/QVGRwG.js",
    async: true,
    success: function(csvd) {
      data = $.csv.toArrays(csvd);
    },
    dataType: "text",
    complete: function() {

      let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
      let type = data[i][5];
      let rarity = data[i][3];
      let item = data[i][0];
      let desc = data[i][1];
      let req = data[i][6];
      let req2 = data[i][7];

      //       Filter query
      if (query === undefined) {
      } else if (rarity !== query && type !== query) {
        return getTreasure();
      }  

      $(".controls").fadeIn("slow");

      let content = `
<div class='type fade-in'>${type}</div>
<div class='rarity'>${rarity}</div>
<div class="cardContainer">
<p class='itemName fade-in'>${item}</p>
<div class="cardContents fade-in">
<div class="description">${desc}</div>
<hr>
<div class='requirement'>${req}<br>${req2}</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class='coin fade-in'><p class="est-value">est.value</p>${data[i][2]}</div>
<div class='weight fade-in'><p class="weight-value">weight</p>${
      data[i][4]
      }</div>
<div class='author fade-in'>${data[i][8]}</div>

<svg stroke='#000000' stroke-width='1' stroke-miterlimit='10' class='path' id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 257 368.51"><title>thing</title><circle class="circleStroke" cx="32.3" cy="338.56" r="21.2" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10"/><path class="weightStroke" d="M750.58,363.36l-6.05-24.19A2.7,2.7,0,0,0,742,337h-5a7.94,7.94,0,1,0-15.42-2.65,7.74,7.74,0,0,0,.49,2.65h-5a2.71,2.71,0,0,0-2.56,2.14l-6,24.19a4.28,4.28,0,0,0,3.84,5.48h34.45C749.37,368.84,751.27,366.12,750.58,363.36Zm-21.06-26.92a2.95,2.95,0,1,1,3-2.94A2.94,2.94,0,0,1,729.52,336.44Z" transform="translate(-511.5 -15.75)" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10"/><path class="innerStroke" d="M521.88,34.31h.33v-.37a9.85,9.85,0,0,1,9.84-9.84H750.3a9.85,9.85,0,0,1,9.85,9.84V366.06a9.85,9.85,0,0,1-9.85,9.84H563.22a29,29,0,1,0-41-41V62.58" transform="translate(-511.5 -15.75)" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10"/><path class="innerStroke" d="M514.36,62.58V361.22a22.53,22.53,0,0,0,22.53,22.53H745.46A22.53,22.53,0,0,0,768,361.22V38.78a22.53,22.53,0,0,0-22.54-22.53H536.89A22.54,22.54,0,0,0,514.8,34.31" transform="translate(-511.5 -15.75)" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10"/><path class="ribbonStroke" d="M670.63,62.58H513.28A1.28,1.28,0,0,1,512,61.29V35.6a1.29,1.29,0,0,1,1.29-1.29H670.63l-7.86,14.13Z" transform="translate(-511.5 -15.75)" style="fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10"/></svg>
`;

      $("#card").html(content)
      $(".fade-in")
        .animate("slow")
        .css("opacity", "1");
      $("hr").css("width", "60%");

      if (type === "Book"){
        $("body").removeClass().addClass('book', 1000);
      } else if (type === "Potion"){
       $("body").removeClass().addClass('potion', 1000); 
      } else if (type === "Armor"){
       $("body").removeClass().addClass('armor', 1000); 
      } else if (type === "Adventuring Gear"){
       $("body").removeClass().addClass('gear', 1000); 
      } else if (type === "Quest Hook"){
       $("body").removeClass().addClass('quest', 1000); 
      } else if (type === "Ring"){
       $("body").removeClass().addClass('ring', 1000); 
      } else if (type === "Treasure"){
       $("body").removeClass().addClass('treasure', 1000); 
      } else if (type === "Weapon"){
       $("body").removeClass().addClass('weapon', 1000); 
      } else if (type === "Wondrous Item"){
       $("body").removeClass().addClass('wondrous-item', 1000); 
      } else $("body").removeClass();

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Rather than randomly getting results and testing them against a query, you should be providing that query element to the endpoint and **it** should be returning you the data that you need.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my questions originally was just that, how do I do that?